# how to import database in mongodb v5?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new on learning MongoDB ,

I'd like to import a JSON file to create a new database using the command `mongoimport`

as I'm using windows I tried to add the executable file name of `mongoimport` to the environment path for easy access it but I didn't find the file in the path, I saw tutors on YouTube have it on version 4 but not exist in v5

this screen from v5 that I have:
[image]

and this from v4 (captured from youtube tut):
[image]

Comment: See the section on Installation in the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) documentation.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I thought that it's not a code and it doesn't matter, I'll replace it with text

Answer (score 0):

mongoexport

```
mongoexport mongodb://localhost:27017 -c=exportcollection --db=mydb --out=exportfile.json
```

mongoimport

```
mongoimport mongodb://localhost:27017 -c=newcollection --db=mydb exportfile.json
```

Comment: thanks, @Yuting but the main problem is that mongoimport ,mongoexport  doesn't exist

Comment: @Ayman Morsy
 Starting with MongoDB 4.4, mongoexport is now released separately from the MongoDB Server and uses its own versioning, with an initial version of 100.0.0. YOU HAVE TO DOWNLOAD [database-tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation/)

Comment: yes, I was missing this info